# Prepared Statements + MySQL (7 day Stats)

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, prepared-statement

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to store 7 days worth of data for each individual object that a user creates, each object has a unique id as well as the user. I guess this is more of a "How do I go about doing this?" vs. "What am I doing wrong?". My goal
is to keep 7 days worth of stats at a time and be able to print them out into jqPlot or some other graphing library based on their object_id.

[image]

My current code for grabbing the data isn't too far along. I just started using prepared statements and I'm not fully understanding the methods for getting results from the query.

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT `date`, `impressions`, `clicks`, `object_id` FROM `object_stats` WHERE `user_id` = ?") or die(mysql_error());
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($date, $impressions, $clicks, $object_id);
$stmt->close();
```

From there I was going to put the results into a multi-dimensional array, and have an array for each object_id, but I had no idea where to even start, I tried googling for similar solutions but I didn't come across anything. I apologize if I'm not fully communicating my problem, I'm having a hard time putting it into words. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `PDO` instead, it has some really cool features, like fetching data into multidimensional arrays with just a simple fetch; this is probably what you're looking for.

Check this tutorial out:

> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

I feel kind today and will provide you with some sample code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `object_id`, `date`, `impressions`, `clicks`  FROM `object_stats` WHERE `user_id` = ?');
$sth->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));

$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like -

```
$object_id_array = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $object_id_array[$object_id][] = array('date'=> $date, 
                                           'impressions'=>$impressions,
                                           'clicks'=>$clicks);
}
```

this would go after `$stmt->bind_result(...)`, but before `$stmt->close();`.

note, `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of `$stmt = $mysql->prepare(...)` will not work on your `mysqli` OO. take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php to see how to get errors.